# HTML5 pushstate and replace state reloading state

Tags: jquery, html, pushstate

I'm having the hardest time figuring this out.

Basically I have a popup that when clicked it pushes the state to the url bar:

```
$(document).on('click', '.youtube_video', function(){
    window.history.pushState("vidPage", "vidPopped", "/video/"+video_id +"");
});
```

This works fine. Now when I click to exit the popup, it returns the previous link(current page) like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.popblock_box_exit', function(){
    window.history.back();
});
```

This works fine. Now when I use the browser button to go forward, it loads the click popup by having this:

```
window.onpopstate = function(e){
    if(e.state !== null) {
        $("#"+ popID).trigger( "click" );
    }
};
```

This works fine, but now when I click to exit the popup it just reloads the popup. I understand that e.state will never be null because I used "history.back", and therefore when clicking exit it just loads the trigger.

How do I stop this popup from constantly reloading?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should check that the state is `"vidPage"` in your `onpopstate` handler. If the previous history entry contains something that's not null, then it will show the popup.

Try `console.log('state:', e.state)` so you can see what state is in that history entry.

*Edit:*

I think the problem might be when you click the Forward button, it triggers the click, it inserts **another** entry in the history, so there would be **two** `vidPage` entries. If you long-press on the back button, you might see an extra entry. Here some contrived code that demonstrates this.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '.youtube_video', function(){
                var video_id = "abc";
                window.history.pushState("vidPage", "vidPopped", "/video/" + video_id + "");
                showVid();
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.popblock_box_exit', function(){
                window.history.back();
                hideVid();
            });

            window.onpopstate = function(e){
                console.log("state", e.state);
                if (e.state == 'vidPage') {
                    var popID = 'vid1';
                    showVid(); // GOOD
                    // $("#"+ popID).trigger( "click" ); // BAD
                } else {
                    hideVid();
                }
            };
        });

        function showVid() { $('#popup').show(); }
        function hideVid() { $('#popup').hide(); }
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="youtube_video" id="vid1">Youtube video</div>

    <div id="popup" style="background: #CCC; display: none;">
      <div class="popblock_box_exit">Exit</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Replace *GOOD* with *BAD* to reproduce the problem.